# How to add MIME type with Express

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, express

I'm trying to get Firefox to play a video tag. Normally, I would just add this to an .htaccess file on Apache:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm

AddType audio/mpeg .mp3
AddType audio/ogg .ogg
AddType audio/mp4 .m4a
AddType audio/wav /wav
```

How would I do this with Express / NodeJS?

Answer (score 6):

For express 4.x, good documentation on mime-type can be found in https://github.com/broofa/node-mime.

For example, Safari browser would *show* the content of csv instead of *downloading* the csv with 
`<a href="some.csv">download here</a>`.

You can get around this by adding the following

```
express.static.mime.define({'application/octet-stream': ['csv']})
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a video in a public directory, you can use the `static` middleware for this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

If you need to alter the mime table (like to add or change an extension, do):

```
express.mime.type['ogv'] = 'video/ogg';
```

But I think all the ones you listed are already there.

Then requests to `/foo.wav` will serve up `/public/foo.wav` with the proper `content-type` header, provided no other middleware handles the route first.

Comment: express.mime.type doesn't work in express 2.5.11 – mime is undefined.

Comment: It should be express.static.mime.type.define(map) but there's a static file you can edit instead I just found.

Answer (score 0):

There is a static text file which is probably better, called "mime.types"