# How to play mp4 video in html video tag in which the video is uploaded via multer

Tags: node.js, html, express, video, multer

I have to play video in my website. The video is uploaded via multer with node.js and in express framework.The file is inserting to the database and the specified folder(file name like 1b47c24b20cc2465fbcb395fd1a9dfb4). I am uploading image also and its showing properly
But video is not playing.

Here is my html code

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Upload image</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" ng-model="testimonial.file" ngf-select ngf-max-size="25MB" required">
<img ng-src="/images/{{testimonial.image.filename}}" width="49" height="49" ng-model="testimonial.file" /><br/>
<label>Upload video</label>
<input type="file" name="video" id="video" ng-model="testimonial.video" ngf-select ngf-max-size="25MB" required">
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="/images/{{testimonial.video.filename}}" type="video/mp4">
<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</div>
```

Please help me to find out the solution. and what is .ogg file how can i generate while uploading my video?

Comment: if you try and play the video by typing browser in a URL does it work? do you have the correct MIME types for the server? to create the ogg version as well you'd want to use ffmpeg from your node application to transcode and upload that as well

Comment: while typing in url is downloading the file.

Comment: what is the MIME type how do I check

Comment: in your .htaccess file (assuming Apache server) add three lines: `AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm`

Comment: its a node server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157400/how-to-add-mime-type-with-express

Comment: @Athi what browser (name/version) downloads the `.mp4` file instead of playing it? Did you try MP4 link in Chrome browser? Anyways might be easier to just provide a link to your problem page so we can assess things. Make a test page & provide link to check...

Comment: _"while typing in url is downloading the file"_ well does this one work if pasted in the address bar : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4 (should play a video and not save anything, if a save happens here too then your browser does not understand MP4 data)

Comment: Which browser you are using? And what version?

Comment: Thank you all. I found out the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while uploading via multer please include extension.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'public/images')
  },
 filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    let extArray = file.mimetype.split("/");
    let extension = extArray[extArray.length - 1];
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now()+ '.' +extension)
  }
})
```

and while displaying via angular use the below code

```
<video controls="controls" ng-src="{{getVideoUrl(data.video[0].filename)}}" width="250" height="180"></video>
```

Angular under controller

```
 $scope.getVideoUrl=function(videopath)
        {
            return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("/images/"+videopath);
        };
```

don't forget to include $sce

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, to display video in different browsers you need different videos extensions.  Here you'll find a list of supported video formats across browsers https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp 
Therefore you need to also convert video on backend side to two lacking formats (if you want to support all browsers). If (as you said) video is downloading instead of showing build in player that means your browser doesn't support this particular video format.

Luckily you can install ffmpeg on your server machine and parse this with wrapper library.

Be advised on obstacles - if nothing changed library very often returns "done" when file is parsed but not saved on hard drive therefore you can't access it instantly but with ms of delay.