# TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': Incorrect response MIME type. Expected 'application/wasm'

Tags: express, webassembly

I'm trying to load a .wasm file using the fetch api on Chrome , and serving a html file using express. But chrome does not let me load the file:

'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': Incorrect response MIME type. Expected 'application/wasm'.'

Here is my files:

/public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch('http://localhost:3000/simple.wasm'))
      .then(obj => {
       console.log(obj.instance.exports.add(1, 2));  // "3"
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Served by Express:

/index.js

```
const express = require('express')
express.static.mime.define({'application/wasm': ['wasm']})
var app = express();

app.use('/', express.static('public'));

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Can i add a new mime type to express when serving a .wasm file? 
Or allow chrome to accept it? 
I dont have any idea for how to solve it ^^

See: http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/compiling/WebAssembly.html

```
Web server setup
To serve wasm in the most efficient way over the network, make sure your web server has the proper MIME time for .wasm files, which is application/wasm. That will allow streaming compilation, where the browser can start to compile code as it downloads.

In Apache, you can do this with

AddType application/wasm .wasm
Also make sure that gzip is enabled:

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/wasm
```

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 21):

One possible workaround is to use `instantiate()` instead of `instantiateStreaming()`, since the former doesn't care about MIME types (while the latter [does](https://www.w3.org/TR/wasm-web-api-1/#streaming-modules)). To use `instantiate()`:

```js
async function fetchAndInstantiate() {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/simple.wasm");
    const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
    const obj = await WebAssembly.instantiate(buffer);
    console.log(obj.instance.exports.add(1, 2));  // "3"
}
```

Comment: But streaming is faster :(

Comment: Is it? Do you have any data to support that argument or you're just relying on the idea of streaming in general, in which you can start processing it before you finish downloading it? If that's the case, I don't think that'll make any significant difference, unless your wasm file is really big.

Comment: For one, either way your "`then()`" code will only run after the wasm file has been totally downloaded, so the only gain would be on the browser side, parsing the partial buffer received right away before it is completely downloaded. I bet, however, that the gain would be negligible if compared to other bottlenecks (network, bad user code, etc)

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: @CarlSmith not sure if you're used to Javascript, but it's implicit here that you must run the code above in a `async` function. I'll edit the answer to add it, just in case.

Comment: @Lucio Palva - The `async` and `await` keywords are new and quite advanced, so I'd appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Loading_and_running#using_fetch @LucioPaiva

Answer (score 5):

The reason is, node.js express.js server failed to recoganize file type .wasm

So it by default set response header to application/octet-stream

[image]

enable express.js recognize .wasm file by,

update type-is version to 1.6.16 +
because 1.6.16 add support .wasm file

[image]

But how to make it work? Share my working example:

1)Now install type-is, run

```
      npm install type-is
```

Make sure package.json type-is version is  1.6.18

[image]

2)make sure your express.js version is 4.17, if not 
update express.js from 4.15 to 4.17 by modify package.json file, 
change 4.15 to 4.17 as picture show
[image]

then run 
          npm install express

4.15 does NOT support type-is, so must upgrade to 4.17

app.js file add log, output current running express version
just make sure it is 4.17

[image]

Now my express.js support .wasm file by response correct header content-type application/wasm

Answer (score 4):

A quick search gives me this answer

```
express.static.mime.define({'application/octet-stream': ['csv']})
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157400/how-to-add-mime-type-with-express)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [the issue](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3589) of Express on github would help.

You just need to wait for the new express published.

Or try [the solution provided by lynncyrin](https://github.com/lynncyrin/galaxy-gen/commit/082a7485faa442d8ed87e8423e27f143e78e8437) (this doesn't help me.)